# Scan QR code within internet explorer

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to scan some QR codes within a text box displayed in Internet Explorer (hereinafter referred to as IE) of a Windows Phone 8.1.I'm trying to avoid the following actions because of the number of steps it requires to complete them:

1. change manually from IE to the camera.
2. capture the QR code.
3. copy it to the clipboard.
4. go back to IE.
5. paste the result from clipboard back to the text box.

I've not developed this web page and I don't want to modify it.

Do you know how to make the IE interpret the QR code scanner as a keyboard?

I want to capture the QR code inside the text box without switching manually between applications.

There is a software keyboard in Android with a button to open a QR scanner, that pastes the string captured from the QR to the text box that actually has the focus. I want to know if there is a similar way to do it in Windows Phone.

Comment: It was not clear what you were asking. I've edited the description of your question to (hopefully) reflect your purpose.

Comment: @Baracuda thanks for the corrections, my english is not so good

Comment: that's fine but still your question seems too broad. Please edit the question and include what you have tried so far and what is the exact problem. Please read the rules about how to ask questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the current iteration of Windows Phone. Currently QR Scanner (aka [Bing Vision](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/scan-codes-and-text)) is just another Camera Lenses (type of app, which gets hooked up to Camera app). There is no way to invoke it from your app, and get its scanned text back.